# A newbie to use Marionette with JQuery-Mobile (JQM)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

Just started to look into marionette and reading the doc.. plus we are new to JQM

Here is how I understand marionette at the ‘very’ high level.
There are concepts of Application and Region, Composite views, etc. to help build complex UI. I can see that within a JQM page, ‘views’ can be built by using marionette’s Regions and Composite views …

Since we are looking into a JQM app with multiple pages, then the question is also if one (1) Marionette Application should manage all the the regions/composite views for all JQM pages.. Or better practice should be each Marionette Application is created for each  JQM page and there will be some sort of routing between the Apps to reflect the JQM page transitions.

Thanks in advance for your patient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in exactly the same boat. I'm trying to find a way to get the best out of Marionette and jQuery Mobile, but am struggling because of my lack of experience with either of the frameworks and the (seeming) lack of available examples of them working together. I'll be watching this question carefully in the hope that someone more qualified than me has a go at answering it. However, I may be able to offer some pointers based on my experiences.

While there do seem to be a lack of examples of Marionette and jQuery Mobile working together, there are a few demonstrating how to integrate plain Backbone and jQuery Mobile. The best I've seen is [this example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/) which uses Backbone's routing but manages the pages using the jQuery Mobile [`changePage`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) method, which means you retain most of the functionality built into jQuery Mobile including the page transitions.

I used the example above as the starting point for [this boilerplate](https://github.com/net-uk-sweet/bbb-phonegap-marionette-jqm-boilerplate), which is an attempt to add Marionette into the mix. It's by no means perfect, as it sacrifices some of the functionality of Marionette (specifically of `Marionette.Application`) to retain the functionality of jQuery Mobile, but it might be interesting to you. I think with a better knowledge of the two frameworks, it may be possible to improve it so that the features of both frameworks are retained.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Will look into your example. I did manage to get backbone and JQM examples running. Also, I wrote a sample app with a few views and a couple of JQM pages, then start seeing myself manually coding what marionette provides, managing the views and no need to add boilerplate code all over the places. 

That is why it makes me interested to look into Marionette.  As you said, we may need someone with great experience in both Marionette and JQM in the community to shed some light on the best practices, which will help us tremendously.

Comment: I have to say, I think having an Application per JQM page sounds overkill to me. I'm currently thinking that each JQM page could be represented by the same Marionette Layout allowing you to inject the appropriate views into the header, content and footer regions from the controller. If you've got any code you can show (github say) I would be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of [`the boilerplate`](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette):

## Packages used

- Marionette
- Backbone
- jQuery & JQM
- JQM router - not backbone router (It is just my preference)

  - In the current version, it is not really being utilized.
- lodash
- requirejs

## App flow - user prospective

- It has three JQM pages: "Landing, About, Login"
- When it launches, it goes to the Landing page.
- From the landing page, user can go to either the "About" or the "Login page."
- From the “About/Login” page, it can go back to other two pages.

## App structure

- All modules are loaded in using requirejs
- There is one Marionette Application instance acting as the central hub
- Each JQM page is modeled as a Marionette Layout, which has three Regions: Header, Content, and Footer. This matches how a JQM page is divided to.
- Each of these Regions (Header, Content, and Footer) contains its Marionette view (Item, Composite, Collection or Layout view). The views can be nested to construct any complex view for your needs.
- The rest are just Backbone/JQM stuffs.
- That is it!

Any thoughts and comments are Welcome!